# What class should access my database?

Tags: unity, architecture, design-patterns, databases

I would like to code a turn-based RPG, and I decided to use a database to store all skills in the game. Now I have to decide as well which class can see this database, and how classes pass around these data.

(Edit: the main reason I would like to use a DB is to avoid editing skills as scriptable objects in the editor. I guess they require too many clicks to edit in games of this type.)

My intuition says that almost every class should be able to see the database, and an attribute of skills can be used as signals.

For example, suppose a skill has attributes `skill_name` and `dialog`. When a player character uses a skill `Strike`, the `character` class spits a signal `skill_used("Strike")`. Any class received this signal will search for `Strike` in the database and does its task. For instance, the `dialogue_manager` shows `dialog` of `Strike`. I don't know how complex the actual coding is, but conceptually it may work.

However, this is like making a massive singleton class `DATABASE`. Any class cannot be tested without the database.

**Question**: Is it fine to allow many classes to access the database? If not, what type of classes should access the database, and how?

Comment: Myself, I would not use a database in this way. It sounds like a single skill use could trigger dozens of redundant look-ups, as each system searches the DB for the skill key to find out what it's supposed to do, instead of just referencing a skill object that has the relevant data/behaviour on hand, without an extra query step.

Comment: Ah-ha, so it seems better to use skills themselves as signals?
The main reason I would like to use a DB is to avoid editing skills as scriptable objects in the editor.

Comment: Yep, you can store your data in the database, but once the game is started, it builds objects based on the database content so it is stored in memory.

Comment: Thank you both, I would consider going that way!

Comment: When making a Pokemon-like monster battler with my students, I built an Excel import pipeline, so we could edit the collection of monsters and skills in a spreadsheet, then have a one-button import routine that would build/update all the ScriptableObjects for us, using the latest spreadsheet contents. If you'd like to ask "How to bulk edit many skills without manually modifying a ScriptableObject for each one" I could walk through that solution.

Comment: Also, my comment was generic and not specific to Unity. When asking a question, it's often better to add more details so that you could get better answer.

Comment: Actually, I wrote this question in a generic way intentionally since I was thinking about code architecture. But implementation may be the most important thing! I am also interested in the bulk edit technology, though it is a bit far from the original question to edit. Could I add it anyway?

Comment: You can always post it as a separate question if you like.